# Head with a weird behavior

Tags: command-line, coreutils

I have downloaded a [warc file](https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2021-25/segments/1623487662882.61/warc/CC-MAIN-20210620114611-20210620144611-00436.warc.gz) from Common Crawl in Ubuntu 18.04. After decompressing it with gzip, I've tried to get a segment of the file using `head`. I first tried:

```
head -c 29 CC-MAIN-20210620114611-20210620144611-00436.warc
```

It produced the expected result, outputting the first 29 bytes of the file:

```
WARC/1.0
WARC-Type: warcinfo
```

But, if instead of 29, I use 30, it produces a result I was not expecting:

```
head -c 30 CC-MAIN-20210620114611-20210620144611-00436.warc
```

Output:

```
WARC/1.0
```

This is only the first 10 bytes of the file, not the first 30. If I use `head -c 31`, the result is the expected back again. I have no idea if this is a bug or if there is a detail on how head works that I'm not aware of.

Comment: If you want to see exactly what's happening, pipe the output to hexdump, with something like `head -c 30 CC-MAIN-20210620114611-20210620144611-00436.warc | hexdump -Cv`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `head` command is almost certainly outputting the requested number of bytes, however what those bytes *are* is affecting how they are displayed in your terminal.

Specifically, your gunzipped file almost certainly has DOS-style CRLF line endings, with a CR at byte 30 and LF at byte 31. When you do `head -c29`, the head output excludes both line ending bytes, and you see something like

```
yourname@computer:~$ head -c29 file.warc
WARC/1.0
WARC-Type: responseyourname@computer:~$
```

with your shell prompt following directly after the 29th byte. When you do `head -c31`, you capture both the CR and the LF, and the output looks like

```
yourname@computer:~$ head -c31 file.warc
WARC/1.0
WARC-Type: response
yourname@computer:~$
```

However when you do `head -c30`, the output contains the terminating CR but not its following LF - the cursor is sent back to position 0, but is left on the same line of the terminal, where it is then overwritten by your shell prompt:

```
yourname@computer:~$ head -c31 file.warc
WARC/1.0
yourname@computer:~$
```

If the line is longer than your prompt, you will see characters from the file peeking out beyond the end. If your `PS1` prompt was empty, then you would have seen the full expected output.

Comment: Or, more practically, just use `head -c 30 filename ; echo`